# How to call createEditor for a row in tableview

Tags: c++, qt

I have a custom delegate that inherits from QStyledItemDelegate. Now certain changes that I make to the widget that I added are only displayed when `createEditor` is triggered how can I trigger createEditor programatically ? I have the row and col and I want to trigger `createEditor` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find the `QModelIndex` by row and column and call `QAbstractItemView::edit(const QModelIndex &index)` to trigger the item's editing.

Comment: Apparently createEditor is not called when I do `TableView->edit(OrdersModel->index(row,2))`

Comment: @MistyD is index returned by `OrdersModel->index(row, 2)` valid? If yes, is item editable?